# To show this $R$ is a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am studying for a qual, and I can't quite figure this one out. Any hints or suggestions for which theorems to use? It might be a very simple problem that I'm just not seeing the solution:

Suppose that $R$ is a Noetherian integral domain and every finitely generated torsion-free $R$-module is free. Show that $R$ is a PID.

I started by taking an ideal in $R$, which must be finitely generated as $R$ is Noetherian. We could quotient out its torsion elements to get a torsion-free module, but I don't see what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ideal of $R$ is already torsion-free *as an $R$-module*. ([Torsion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_%28algebra%29) at Wikipedia.) So by assumption it is free.

Now show that an ideal can never be a free $R$-module unless it is generated by a single element. (Hint: give a nontrivial relation over $R$ between any two nonzero elements of the ideal.)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Now I see there is a contradiction to linear independence if there is more than 1 element generating the ideal.